# GWT platform independent newline character

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

In one of my java classes, I want to write a result that looks something like this:

```
String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.lineSeparator();
Stringbuilder result = new Stringbuilder();
result.append("some characters");
result.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
```

The class using this code is passed to a GWT based frontend. GWT compiles all java classes that are used by GWT (e.g. all classes in the fronted) into javascript. However, GWT cannot compile System.lineSeparator() as there is no equivalent method in javascript.

```
String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty(line.separator);
```

and

```
String LINE_SEPARATOR = String.format("%n");
```

also cause GWT compiler exceptions. However,

```
String LINE_SEPARATOR = "\r\n";
```

works, but is not platform independent.

How can I get a platform independent newline character that is compatible to GWT?

Comment: why not just use `<br>` tag?

Comment: The result string is also used outside of html environment e.g. logging and writing result into a file.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest thing that could possibly work (out of the top of my head):

```java
String LINE_SEPARATOR = GWT.isClient() ? "\n" : getLineSeparator();

@GwtIncompatible
private static String getLineSeparator() {
  return System.lineSeparator();
}
```

That would require a recent version of GWT (2.6 at least, maybe 2.7).

The alternative would be to use super-source with a simple provider class:

```java
public class LineSeparatorProvider {
  public final String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.lineSeparator();
}

// in super-source
public class LineSeparatorProvider {
  public final String LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";
}
```

Note that in a future version of GWT, `System.getProperty` will work (for some properties) so you could possibly make it work for `line.separator`.

…**OR**, you could use `\n` everywhere and only when you really need to have `\r\n` then do a `replace("\n", "\r\n")`.

(if you ask me, I'd just use `\n` everywhere, even on Windows)

Comment: If getLineSeparator() has the @GwtIncompatible tag, the method is not compiled in javascript and GWT throws a method not found exception. Because the method is called in the if statement and no source is found.

Comment: The super-source idea seems a bit overkill so I will stick with the "\n" solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be:

```
String systemLineSeparator;
String platform = Window.Navigator.getPlatform();
if(platform.toLowerCase().contains("windows")) {
    systemLineSeparator = "\r\n";
}
else {
    systemLineSeparator = "\n";
}
```

A more advanced solution could use deferred binding.

Comment: Window.Navigator.getPlatform() works fine with GWT. When I execute the code in native Java, I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Comment: You could setup your lineSeparator-variable during bootstrapping of your application. On the server you use System.lineSeparator(). On the client Window.Navigator.

Comment: Without much actual use, I found the line separator string must be determined in client code and then passed to shared / server code.  I used this solution as the basis for [my experiment](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/learn/gwt/src/main/java/biz/freshcode/learn/gwt2/common/client/util/ClientUtil.java).